# Doubt/Confusion in De Broglie Wavelength of a particle in a box setup

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavelength

So I am pretty new to quantum mechanics (mostly related to atomic structures), and have some difficulties in the following setup:

> Consider a particle of mass $m$ confined to a one-dimensional box of length
> $L$. The particle moves
> in the box with momentum
> $p$ colliding elastically with the walls. We consider the quantum
> mechanics of this system.
>
> At each energy state, the particle may be represented by a standing wave given by the de Broglie hypothesis. Express its wavelengths
> $λ_{dB}$ in terms of
> $L$ in the
> $n^{\text{th}}$ energy state.

First of all, (it may seem silly), what is energy state here? In atomic structure, I know it corresponds to electrons permissible energy in shells, as per Bohr's quantization. But here in this setup, I couldn't grasp the meaning of 'energy state'.

Secondly, question asked to express particle as a standing wave. I know the standing wave concept but from a classical mechanics point of view, not quantum mechanical. I couldn't figure which concept should I apply here.[image]

Interestingly, the answer is $\lambda_{dB}=\frac{2L}{n}$, which is the same as the general formula of standing wave (classical) wavelength as shown in the figure. I don't know how the $n$ in the figure of standing waves and the
$n$ corresponding to energy state in our state are so related, so this is my major doubt. I may be confused between these formulae, but I can't help myself here.

Please help clear my doubts/confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the energy for a particle in a box is as follows:
$$E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8mL^2}$$
Where each n represent the state, so $E_n$ represents the energy per state.

The n in the lambda represents the excited state of the wavelength, so for n=1 you have the ground state, n=2 is the first excited state etc. It represents the amount of knots etc in a wave. Hope this cleared things up! If not, let me know.

To come back to your question of where this formula came from:
The momentum is known to be $p=m v \longrightarrow v = \frac{p}{m}$
Inside a one-dimensional box there's kinetic energy: $E= \frac{1}{2}mv^2$. We can rewrite this as $E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$.
since $p = \frac{h}{\lambda} = \frac{hn}{2L}$
So we get $$E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8mL^2}$$ when we plug all of this in.

Comment: Can you please, tell that how you wrote $E_n$? I am pretty novice in quantum mechanics. I know nothing beyond basic quantum mechanical model of atom.

Comment: I included that now, take a look. @KshitijKumar

Comment: By the way, $p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$ because $p = \frac{E}{c} = \frac{hf}{c} = \frac{h}{\lambda}$

Comment: One more doubt is that wavelength gets shorter for increasing value of $n$, so is it sort of frequency like factor? Also how are we exciting particle, through external means?

Comment: Yeah the wavelength gets shorter, because for a higher n, the energy increases. I'm not sure what you mean with the last question. @KshitijKumar

Comment: *At each energy state, the particle may be represented by a standing wave given by the de Broglie hypothesis.* That's very poorly worded. The wave function $\psi$ doesn't really 'represent' anything. The wave function isn't even observable (often it is complex (i.e. imaginary))

Comment: I think it's meant to give a visual example of the particle, which is a standing wave. They're talking about the particle being a wave, and not the wave function. @Gert

Comment: @AnonymousRU Except of course: the particle isn't really a wave. QM is more complicated than mere de Broglie.

Comment: Since there’s a wave-particle duality, i’m not quite sure what you mean with “except the particle isn’t really a wave”. A particle in a one dimensional box will always behave like a wave. @Gert

Comment: @AnonymousRU No, not really. $\psi$ isn't observable. And when you try and measure position (or momentum) it collapses. The only thing that's really wavy here is $|\psi|^2$: the probability density.

Comment: @AnonymousRU $\psi$ is very often Complex. A complex wave? How can that even be a wave, as it is not even Real? $\psi$ contains all the information about the system there is to know (1st post. of QM) and that's about it.

Comment: @AnonymousRU You should really study this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude

Comment: I know about the wave function and the probability amplitude lmao. Just trying to get the message to you that those things don’t have anything to do with the asked question- we’re talking about a particle behaving as a **wave** inside of a one dimensional box, not the wave function. @Gert

Comment: And yes, when you take the root of the wave function you get the probability distribution in the one dimensional box, but we’re not talking about that here. I think you got it mixed up in the beginning where you thought the wave function was represented by something written in the question, while that wasn’t the case.

Comment: @AnonymousRU If anyone is confused here it's you sir. Have a good day and the last word if you wish. I have better things to do.